# How to reactively pass parameters to sveltekit load function?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

```
    export async function load({fetch,session}){
    const response = await fetch(`https://atlas.mapmyindia.com/api/places/geocode?address=${curcity}&bias=1&podFilter=city&itemCount=3`,
    {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ********-****-****-****-**********`}})
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
}
```

**{curcity} is what i want to change reactively**

I tried the basic ways on how we do it but it doesn't seem to work out ? Any suggestion how to do it . ways i tried includes storing it in store and reading it directly from there instead
*Context*
The suggestion changes depending what you are typing , suggestion for your city address

Answer (score 0):

You could reactively use [`goto`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto) to update the current location with a query or [additional route parameters](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing). The query would be read from the `url` and parameters from `params`.

```js
export async function load({ params, url }) {
  // if something like goto('/search/{value}') with route /search/[value]
  const { value } = params;

  // if something like goto('/search?query={value}') with route /search
  const query = url.searchParams.get('query')
}
```

If you do not want to change the URL, you might have to a `fetch` to a separate endpoint instead.